# cumsum by group

Tags: r, cumsum

Suppose data looks like

```
group1 group2 num
A      sg     1
A      sh     2
A      sg     4
B      at     3
B      al     7
```

`a <- cumsum(data[,"num"]) # 1 3 7 10 17`

I need something accumulated by groups. In reality,I have multiple columns as grouping indicators. I want to get the accumulated sum by the subgroup I define.

**E.g**

If I group by `group1` only, then the output should be

```
group1 sum
A      1
A      3
A      7
B      3
B      10
```

If I group by two variables `group1,group2` then the output is

```
group1 group2 sum
A      sg     1
A      sh     2
A      sg     5
B      at     3
B      al     7
```

Comment: Try for instance: `ave(df$num,df$group1,FUN=cumsum)` for summing on just `group1` or `ave(df$num,df$group1,df$group2,FUN=cumsum)` for both groups.

Comment: This should be basic group by operation.  Using `data.table` `setDT(data)[, cumsum(num), list(group1, group2)]` or `data %>% group_by(group1, group2) %>% mutate(sum=cumsum(num))` with `dplyr`

Comment: @nicola didn't notice `ave` has option for `FUN`!

Comment: @akrun. I haven't heard of this package. Will check it out later. The syntax looks weird.

Comment: @W_ee which one the `data.table` or `dplyr`.  `dplyr` is created to make things easier to understand.

Comment: @akrun `dplyr`, Well, its name is already difficult to understand. Haven't found out what `dplyr` stands for.

Comment: @W_ee I read in some posts that it acts like the `plier`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77997/discussion-between-w-ee-and-akrun).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
library(data.table)

data <- data.table(group1=c('A','A','A','B','B'),sum=c(1,2,4,3,7))

data[,list(cumsum = cumsum(sum)),by=list(group1)]
```

Answer (score 6):

In addition to using `data.table`, `tapply` in base R works fine for both of these cases:

```
dta <- read.table(text="
group1 group2 num
A      sg     1
A      sh     2
A      sg     4
B      at     3
B      al     7", header=TRUE)

dta$cumsum <- do.call(c, tapply(dta$num, dta$group1, FUN=cumsum))
```

Calculating the cumulative sum by two groups requires some reordering:

```
dta <- dta[order(dta$group1, dta$group2, dta$num),]

dta$cumsum2 <- do.call(c, tapply(dta$num, 
                                 paste0(dta$group1, dta$group2), 
                                 FUN=cumsum))
dta
      group1 group2 num cumsum cumsum2
1      A     sg   1      1       1
3      A     sg   4      7       5
2      A     sh   2      3       2
5      B     al   7     10       7
4      B     at   3      3       3
```

And if you need the original order back:

```
dta[as.numeric(rownames(dta)),]
  group1 group2 num cumsum cumsum2
1      A     sg   1      1       1
2      A     sh   2      3       2
3      A     sg   4      7       5
4      B     at   3      3       3
5      B     al   7     10       7
```

Comment: Nice! I would just add `simplify = FALSE` to that `tapply()` call for the sake of type safety.